# Nervgh Angular File Upload - How do I restrict the file formats to say jpeg and png?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I am upgrading an application that is using nv-file-select directive. I am unsure as to how to restrict the file formats supported for upload.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the filters as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#directives).

Create the filter:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: '/api/users/photo'
});

// FILTERS

uploader.filters.push({
    name: 'imageFilter',
    fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
        var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
        return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
    }
});
```

Docs suggests entering it in the HTML, such as I have done below:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" filters="imageFilter">
```

This code was used on his [sample site](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/) that allows for image only uploads.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928826/only-allow-specific-file-extensions-in-angular-file-upload-module-to-be-clickabl):

You can simply achieve your goal by doing this

accept=".txt"

```
<input ui-jq="filestyle" type="file" nv-file-select="" accept=".txt" uploader="uploader" data-icon="false" data-classButton="btn btn-default" data-classInput="form-control inline v-middle input-s" multiple>
```