# Only allow specific file extensions in angular-file-upload module to be clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using this module, https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

I am using their simple example, http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/

When you click "Choose file" button, it will open a window which allows us to pick a file that we want to upload. What I would like to happen is to only allow specific file extensions to be clicked. Is there a non-documented configuration which will do that?

For example, in the config, we only allowed .txt extensions, when I click "Choose file" button, it will open up a window and show all the files. However, files that doesn't have the extension .txt will be disabled.

I'm not doing this for security purposes. I am just following the design/instructions provided to me. :) I can always use mitm tools to intercept and allow other extensions to be uploaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply achieve your goal by doing this

**accept=".txt"**

```
<input ui-jq="filestyle" type="file" nv-file-select="" accept=".txt" uploader="uploader" data-icon="false" data-classButton="btn btn-default" data-classInput="form-control inline v-middle input-s" multiple>
```

[more information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)

Comment: I also got it to work using this code     uploader.filters.push({
      name: 'customFilter',
      fn: function(item) {
        return /\/(txt)$/.test(item.type)
      }
    });

Comment: I'll try your suggestion too

Comment: WOW, my answer is only filtering and your answer is the answer I really like! Thank you so much!!!!! :D

Comment: what if i only want to accept extensions, png, gif and jpg, what will be the code? Will it be like this? accept=".txt|.png|.gif|.jpg"

Comment: @devwannabe If I want to disallow specific file types, what should I do?

Comment: @devwannabe If you want to filter multi files, use this: [accept]="['.doc','.docx','.pdf']"